# Error "near 'WHERE' : Syntax error in WHERE NOT EXIST SQLite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

a sqlite error like `near 'WHERE' : Syntax error` has occurred in below code:

```
INSERT INTO [Question_Period] ([Question_Period_ID],[Question_ID],[Period_ID],[Question_Period_Status])
SELECT 0,[Question_ID],0,1 FROM [Question] WHERE [Question_Property] = 1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [Question_Period] WHERE question_id in(SELECT 
[Question_ID] WHERE [Question_Property] = 1));
```

I used `INSERT OR IGNORE` but nothing worked!

Comment: You have `where` twice... Format your question and you will see it.  `where not exists` should be `and not exists`... Also your last subquery is missing a `from` statement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Right SQL is:

```
INSERT INTO [Question_Period] ([Question_Period_ID],[Question_ID],[Period_ID],[Question_Period_Status])
SELECT 0,[Question_ID],0,1 FROM [Question] WHERE [Question_Property] = 1 
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [Question_Period] WHERE question_id in(SELECT 
[Question_ID] FROM [Question] WHERE [Question_Property] = 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use more than one `Where` clause for a single `Select`, use `AND` to separate the condition

```
INSERT INTO [question_period] 
            ([question_period_id], 
             [question_id], 
             [period_id], 
             [question_period_status]) 
SELECT 0, 
       [question_id], 
       0, 
       1 
FROM   [question] 
WHERE  [question_property] = 1 
       AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1  -- Here use AND instead of Where
                      FROM   [question_period] 
                      WHERE  question_id IN(SELECT [question_id] 
                                            FROM   yourmissing_table  --From clause missing
                                            WHERE  [question_property] = 1));
```

**Note :** I think your query can be re-written in a better way if you share sample data and expected result

Comment: The last where is there for preventing same record and isnt part of first select

Comment: @MahdiAstanei - But we dont know the table name

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your second line in parenthesis ... like this:

```
INSERT INTO [Question_Period] ([Question_Period_ID],[Question_ID],
                                [Period_ID],[Question_Period_Status])
   (SELECT 0,[Question_ID],0,1 FROM [Question] WHERE [Question_Property] = 1) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [Question_Period] WHERE question_id in(SELECT 
   [Question_ID] WHERE [Question_Property] = 1));
```